# How to make changes in the Ubuntu interface?

Tags: 12.04, interface

Suppose I want to make a change
 *I want to change the interfaces ( battery status bar time display and username) to the left side* 
So how can we edit them.
How are they programmed? 
What programming language is used to built the interfaces?

Comment: @minerz029 its just an approach to know  the new things about the ubuntu interface and I got suggestion to have different threads of question and not repeating all threads in one.
And the questions are not duplicate they both resemble different queries

Comment: My apologies if it is indeed a different question, however both the questions looked fundamentally similar ("how can we edit them. How are they programmed? What programming language is used to built the interfaces?")

Comment: please visit this link: [How can I move the System menu on the top bar to the left side?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89717/how-can-i-move-the-system-menu-on-the-top-bar-to-the-left-side).. If you don't like the appearance of the Unity desktop you could try using different other [desktop environments available for Ubuntu/Linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)..

Answer (score 0):

One great way of achieving most of these tasks without having to touch the code is by installing `gnome-tweak-tool` with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

This tool will be able to achieve most of what you want to do. Whatever it can't do can usually be done with some tweaking in `dconf Editor` (available from the dash).